# Jquery ui resizable as Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement Jquery ui resizable plugin as an Angular directive. It's almost successful. But when I set explicitly handler for resizable plugin I get an error whenever I click on any dom item.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined
```

Here is angular directive;

```
App.directive('resizable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).resizable({
                handles: { 's' : '.handle' }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Html;

```
<div class="row list-box" resizable>
<div class="handle ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n fa fa-ellipsis-h"></div>
```

Also what's the best practice for using jquery ui with angularjs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Problem is handler `div` is not placed in `resizable div`. After placing it correctly it worked as expected.

```
<div class="row list-box" resizable>
    ...
    <div class="handle ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n fa fa-ellipsis-h"></div>
</div>
```